# Dungeon Siege Character Races?

Tags: dungeon-siege

In multiplayer Dungeon Siege there are some different ways to make your character look, such as a regular dude or a skeleton, or in the expansion, a giant looking thing.  Are there any differences between these or is it just for looks?

Comment: Is this question about the series in general, or about a specific game in it? I will help create a tag if it is the latter and we do not have a tag for that game.

Comment: I should have specifed.  I am asking about the original game and it's expansion. (Legends of Arannia I think it's called.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The difference is only cosmetic.  Unlike Dungeon Siege 2, your appearance has no effect on your character.